# Добавление капчи Google "я не робот"

Tags: html, css, recaptcha

1. Возможно ли добавить капчу на локальном сервере?
2. Как эта правильно делается для обычной формы (поделитесь ссылкой, нашел только под wordpress)?

Comment: да можно, просто в списке доменов добавить localhost. [полезная статья](https://itchief.ru/lessons/php/how-to-install-recaptcha-on-website)

Comment: возможно эта статья пригодится:
[reCAPTCHA](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024)

Comment: Да хоть на html файлике

Answer (score 6):

Мне помогла вот [эта статья](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/ru/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024), всё довольно подробно описано

Если вкратце:

1. Нужно получить [API key](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin) и там в настройках указать домен вашего сайта (localhost, если вы хотите протестировать работу капчи на локалке).
   Там же вам предоставляется кусок html который нужно скопировать в форму и файл скрипта:

`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`

2. Когда вы всё это подключите при отправке формы на сервер вместе с полями будет передаваться значение 'get-recaptcha-response'

Ещё один момент, если вы не используете функцию serialize, а вручную собираете поля и отправляете аяксом, то и поле get-racaptcha-response тоже нужно получить вручную, как-то так:

```
_formData['g-recaptcha-response'] = grecaptcha.getResponse();
```

функция grecaptcha.getResponse() определена в скрипте, который вы подключили (пункт 1)

3. Теперь когда отправили код капчи на сервер нужно обработать запрос на сервере. Подключите файл с вот этим кодом к вашему PHP-обработчику формы:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * This is a PHP library that handles calling reCAPTCHA.
     *    - Documentation and latest version
     *          https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php
     *    - Get a reCAPTCHA API Key
     *          https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
     *    - Discussion group
     *          http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha
     *
     * @copyright Copyright (c) 2014, Google Inc.
     * @link      http://www.google.com/recaptcha
     *
     * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
     * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
     * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
     * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
     * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
     * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
     *
     * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
     * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
     *
     * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
     * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
     * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
     * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
     * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
     * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
     * THE SOFTWARE.
     */
    /**
     * A ReCaptchaResponse is returned from checkAnswer().
     */
    class ReCaptchaResponse
    {
        public $success;
        public $errorCodes;
    }
    class ReCaptcha
    {
        private static $_signupUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin";
        private static $_siteVerifyUrl =
            "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?";
        private $_secret;
        private static $_version = "php_1.0";
        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param string $secret shared secret between site and ReCAPTCHA server.
         */
        function ReCaptcha($secret)
        {
            if ($secret == null || $secret == "") {
                die("To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from <a href='"
                    . self::$_signupUrl . "'>" . self::$_signupUrl . "</a>");
            }
            $this->_secret=$secret;
        }
        /**
         * Encodes the given data into a query string format.
         *
         * @param array $data array of string elements to be encoded.
         *
         * @return string - encoded request.
         */
        private function _encodeQS($data)
        {
            $req = "";
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $req .= $key . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
            }
            // Cut the last '&'
            $req=substr($req, 0, strlen($req)-1);
            return $req;
        }
        /**
         * Submits an HTTP GET to a reCAPTCHA server.
         *
         * @param string $path url path to recaptcha server.
         * @param array  $data array of parameters to be sent.
         *
         * @return array response
         */
        private function _submitHTTPGet($path, $data)
        {
            $req = $this->_encodeQS($data);
            $response = file_get_contents($path . $req);
            return $response;
        }
        /**
         * Calls the reCAPTCHA siteverify API to verify whether the user passes
         * CAPTCHA test.
         *
         * @param string $remoteIp   IP address of end user.
         * @param string $response   response string from recaptcha verification.
         *
         * @return ReCaptchaResponse
         */
        public function verifyResponse($remoteIp, $response)
        {
            // Discard empty solution submissions
            if ($response == null || strlen($response) == 0) {
                $recaptchaResponse = new ReCaptchaResponse();
                $recaptchaResponse->success = false;
                $recaptchaResponse->errorCodes = 'missing-input';
                return $recaptchaResponse;
            }
            $getResponse = $this->_submitHttpGet(
                self::$_siteVerifyUrl,
                array (
                    'secret' => $this->_secret,
                    'remoteip' => $remoteIp,
                    'v' => self::$_version,
                    'response' => $response
                )
            );
            $answers = json_decode($getResponse, true);
            $recaptchaResponse = new ReCaptchaResponse();
            if (trim($answers ['success']) == true) {
                $recaptchaResponse->success = true;
            } else {
                $recaptchaResponse->success = false;
                $recaptchaResponse->errorCodes = $answers [error-codes];
            }
            return $recaptchaResponse;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Далее в обработчике нужно создать класс ReCapcha и вызвать функцию verifyResponse:

```
// ваш секретный ключ
$secret = "6LcePAATAAAAABjXaTsy7gwcbnbaF5XgJKwjSNwT";
 
// пустой ответ
$response = null;
 
// проверка секретного ключа
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

// if submitted check response
if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
    $response = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
}

if ($response != null && $response->success) {
    echo "Hi " . $_POST["name"] . " (" . $_POST["email"] . "), thanks for submitting the form!";
}
```